# Wildcard Domains with GoDaddy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I've read Heroku's documentation:

http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#wildcard_domains

They say to add:

> To use with a custom domain, configure your DNS registrar to point *.yourdomain.com at yourapp.heroku[app].com.

In GoDaddy, you can't do:

```
*.yourdomain.com
```

in the name field. I've heard you can get around that by doing:

```
**
```

However, I tried that, but it's not working.

When I run this in console:

```
 host anysub.yourdomain.com
```

I get:

```
 Host anysub.yourdomain.com not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
```

What could be the problem? I'm guessing the wildcard isn't set up in GoDaddy correctly?

(FYI: I swapped out yourdomain.com for my actual domain.)

Comment: you should check the other answer now

Comment: CNAME support asked at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17231156/wildcard-cname-for-godaddy

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Go to GoDaddy's DNS Manager, the first table on top should say **A(Host)**, click the button under that first table that says **Quick Add**. In the first text field, enter an asterisk **(*)**, in the second one, the IP address to redirect to (the same one you have for the **@** record on top). Click "**Save Zone File**" on top-right and confirm.

This creates a *catch-all* record to `anysub.yourdomain.com`.

Good luck.

Comment: Is this possible as a `CNAME` instead?

Comment: So, Heroku has three IPs that they suggest you set for A(Host) Records. So I should just pick one of those IPs to point * to? That worked with A(Host). No way to do it with a CNAME?

Comment: and make sure you read this http://neilmiddleton.com/the-dangers-of-a-records-and-heroku/ to know the pitfalls of using those IP addresses in your DNS.

Comment: There's no way to do it with a CNAME, sorry. Also, you can't have a *catch-all* subdomain pointing to more than one IP, so you'll have to pick one, but do read John's suggestion.

Comment: And in case this isn't obvious to others (it wasn't to me), this wildcard A record will *not* override any other explicit subdomain A records.

Answer (score 19):

I just tried it today and it seems that it's now possible to create wildcard cnames in GoDaddy.

GoDaddy > ... > DNS Manager -> Zone File Editor (Edit Zone)

Then under CNAME (Alias) panel > Quick Add

```
Host: *
Points to: yourapp.herokuapp.com
```

Or

```
Host: *.dev.herokuapp.com
Points to: yourapp.herokuapp.com
```

Then click on "Save Zone File" and wait a few minutes.

I remember getting this "Host not found 3(NXDOMAIN)" error myself not so long ago. Not anymore. 
Any subdomain other than those listed explicitly in either A or CNAME are redirected as expected.

Comment: wow, just checked this out, it is true, godaddy now has wildcard CNAMEs, this is awesome

Answer (score 0):

I had this challenge recently and I tried all of the above, but none of them worked for me. After days of surfing I found a solution.
If your app is hosted on heroku, you'd usually not have a static IP Address and so the wild card A record will not work as the IP keeps changing

```
GoDaddy > ... > Manage DNS > ADD record
```

Record Type is

```
CNAME
```

Host

```
*
```

Points to your heroku app

Note: you can't do this if you already have a wild card A record

Answer (score 0):

go to ->goddady cpanel->select subdomain

**Create a Subdomain**

**Subdomain add** *

```
*
```

in domain

```
yourdomain.com
```

then enter create